# Kettle - Use ${filename} variable

Tags: xml, csv, filenames, pentaho, kettle

How can I use the **${filename} variable?** I'm reading some XML files, to create a CSV file, which contains information about all those XML files, including their names: one of the columns of the CSV file will be the name of each XML file. How can I get their names?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the `Get data from XML` and the `XML Input Stream (StAX)` steps, you have the ability to add the filename to the output of the step. It's on the 'Additional output fields' tab for the `Get data from XML` step and the checkbox called 'Include filename in output' for the StAX step.